# Terminate Python Program, but Recover Data

Tags: python, terminate, recovery

I have an inefficient simulation running (it has been running for ~24 hours).

It can be split into 3 independent parts, so I would like to cancel the simulation, and start a more efficient one, but still recover the data that has already been calculated for the first part.

When an error happens in a program, for example, you can still access the data that the script was working with, and examine it to see where things went wrong.

Is there a way to kill the process manually without losing the data?

Comment: It depends on how and where you're scoring the data and how your script looks like, but if you started the script with the -i option from the command line, you'll land back at a python shell after an exception and should be able to examine the stack manually from there.

Comment: I'm using IDLE. The data are just stored in a list.

Comment: Just write the data to the file and flush it after each entry is written to the file. After you kill the python interpreter, the file has the contents of everything written so far.

Comment: How do I do that if the program is already running? (Note ... I'm still pretty new to Python).

Answer (score 2):

You could start a debugger such as [winpdb](http://winpdb.org/about/), or any of several IDE debuggers, in a separate session, attach to the running process, (this halts it), set a break point in a section of the code that has access to your data, resume until you reach the break point and then save your data to a file, your new process could then load that data as a starting point.